# Composite primary key with autoincrement field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I working with sqlite3 and I have the following tables and I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the result described below as the wanted behavior. I am not sure how useful this would be, but seems like it could be useful in the future.

I have the following tables:

```
topics:
  topic_id int primary key,
  topic_name str,
  topic_author str,

posts:
  tid int,
  pid integer primary key autoincrement,
  post_author str,
  post str,
  FOREIGN KEY(tid) REFERENCES topics(topic_id)
```

When i insert into the the table posts:

```
  15, null, "Author1", "Post1"
  15, null, "Author1", "Post2"
  16, null, "Author1", "Post1"
  16, null, "Author1", "Post1"
```

I get:

```
  15, 1, "Author1", "Post1"
  15, 2, "Author1", "Post2"
  16, 3, "Author1", "Post1"
  16, 4, "Author1", "Post1"
```

instead what I would wanted:

```
  15, 1, "Author1", "Post1"
  15, 2, "Author1", "Post2"
  16, 1, "Author1", "Post1"
  16, 2, "Author1", "Post1"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can only do this with a trigger.

Comment: Not using `autoincrement`, maybe triggers. Could you explain why do you need such a feature ? Do you also need to renumber all records when some record is removed from the middle? Is this mechanizm supposed to work in multiuser enviroment (many simultanous connection inserting/updating/deleting) ? The latter may be very hard and tricky to implement, even if you manage to implement this, it will kill the system performance.

Comment: It looked like that would be the appropriate result, but maybe that had to do with my lack of experience. I see the problems you are describing and why that would be a not so practical approach.

Comment: Forget this idea, it's not the good way. You'll use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY pid` will be ok, even with the default `autoincrement` behaviour.